# c++ xml parser function not working

Tags: xml-parsing

I am using xerces c++ to manipulate an xml file? but getNodeValue() and setNodeValue() are not working but getNodeName() is working. Do anyone has any suggestions?

```
 if( currentNode->getNodeType() &&  currentNode->getNodeType() == DOMNode::ELEMENT_NODE ) 
         {
        // Found node which is an Element. Re-cast node as element
            DOMElement* currentElement= dynamic_cast< xercesc::DOMElement* >( currentNode );
            if( XMLString::equals(currentElement->getTagName(), TAG_ApplicationSettings))
            {
               // Already tested node as type element and of name "ApplicationSettings".
               // Read attributes of element "ApplicationSettings".
               const XMLCh* xmlch_OptionA = currentElement->getAttribute(ATTR_OptionA);
               m_OptionA = XMLString::transcode(xmlch_OptionA);
                   XMLCh* t,*s;
        //s= XMLString::transcode("manish");
        //currentNode->setElementText(s);
                  t=(XMLCh*)currentNode->getNodeName();
               s=(XMLCh*)currentNode->getNodeValue();
```

cout<getNodeValue()) << "\n";

Comment: there is no error its just not working

Comment: so what is the node you're parsing, what are expecting, what are you getting ?

Answer (score 1):

A `DOMElement` may contain a collection of other `DOMElements` or a `DOMText`. To get the text value of an element you need to call the method `getTextContent()`, `getNodeValue` will always return `NULL`. 
The is another better way conceptually, as the `DOMText` is a child of the `DOMElement` we can traverse through the child node and get the value.

Below is the logic in the form of a method:

```
string getElementValue(const DOMElement& parent)
{    
 DOMNode *child;   

 string strVal;

 for (child = parent.getFirstChild();child != NULL ; child = child->getNextSibling())    
 {    
    if(DOMNode::TEXT_NODE == child->getNodeType())    
    {    
     DOMText* data = dynamic_cast<DOMText*>(child);    
     const XMLCh* val = data->getWholeText();    
     strVal += XMLString::transcode(val);    
    }    
    else    
    {    
        throw "ERROR : Non Text Node";    
    }    
 }    
 return strVal;   
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

`getNodeValue()` will always return an empty string, because the "value" of an element node is in its child. In our case it is text node child. Either way is to iterate through child nodes 
or use `getTextContent`.
First check for child nodes in a node using `hasChildNodes()` then use methods like `getFirstChild()` etc. . Afterwards use `getNodeValue()`.

```
DOMNode* ptrDomNode = SomeNode;

if(ptrDomNode->hasChildNodes())
{
    DOMNode* dTextNode =  ptrDomNode->getFirstChild();         
    char* string = XMLString::transcode(dTextNode->getNodeValue());
}
```